# Why is GZip compression not working

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate

I have tried GZip code provided by gtmatrix and it works fine on many website 
but now when I try it on one of my website its not working.

I have checked using `phpinfo()` and the GZip shows enabled.

But when I check website it ask for GZip compression. Why it happens?

And when I click to that GZip tab all they are JavaScript so I tried both of below code

I tried first.

```
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Then for JavaScript:

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</ifmodule>
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

> I have checked using phpinfo() and the GZip shows enabled.

Then you are showing snippets of code that are clearly Apache2 configs or .htaccess overrides for Apache2 that activate [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html). Two different things. Are you in control of your Apache2 server on an admin level?  Are you sure that `mod_deflate` is installed & active on that setup?

The thing is that what is shown in `phpinfo()` is strictly for PHP and controlled within `php.ini`.  If your server is set with PHP level Gzip compression, that is a completely different thing than Apache configs or .htaccess settings that adjust for [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

That said, how are you testing that Gzip compression? Via an online tool? I prefer to use [the GIDNetwork test page](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) for Gzip compression tests. Very simple & clear.

Comment: hi thanks...how i can check mod_deflate is available?when i check your suggested tool it shows compressed with gzip but in gtmatrix or google pagespeed it ask for gzip and they all are js